# Naming Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Can I name the stored procedure starting with number? Are there any rules for naming stored procedure? I tried creating a stored procedure with 01_01_03. I am not getting it.

Comment: Read here to learn more about [`Database Identifiers`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

Comment: Old but still valid. [Using identifiers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223962(v=sql.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
create proc [dbo].[01_01_03]
as
BEGIN
--ur code
END
```

I am able to create